# Export table to other table don't map REPEATED fields rightly

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to export my table to other table before change their schema.
But, if i create a new empty table with the same schema when i try to export using web interface shows the message who my repeated fields weren't found.
If i try export to a new table with no schema it has mapped to a new table (tool reports success) and the repeated fields were not mapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you could run a copy job, which would preserve the schema.

Comment: Tks Joardan, but i'm trying copy part of table (using where) there are any command in bq who i can do? 
I can export to gs: and load in other table (it works), but my resultset is about 10gb, was created lot of json files and needs load one by one (i can use loop, but still slow).
Maybe in bq can have a character to import all files .json like gs://bck/custo*.json cust_schema.json cause the exported files as called cust0001.json, cust0002.json and keep the data structure
if i try in web with export to table checked(i guess it would faster) not works, as Fh said bellow.

Comment: importing gs://bck/custo* works (but not gs://bck/custo*.json)

Answer (score 2):

Update since this question was originally asked:  BigQuery now exposes a [flattenResults](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.flattenResults) boolean option when specifying a query configuration:

> configuration.query.flattenResults (boolean)
>
> [Experimental] Flattens all nested and repeated fields in the query results. The
> default value is true. allowLargeResults must be true if this is set
> to false.

This is also exposed in the web UI under the "show options" button for your query.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery used to enforce flattening of results, but not anymore. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25193966/132438

Comment: Thanks for the information.
In the other reply i have detailed what i tried to do. I hope my suggestion be helpful.